# VS2012 Error when creating publish package: Exception in Executing Publishing Access to path is denied

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, msdeploy

I am trying to publish an application with VS2012 and when i try and make the package i get an error that access to the path is denied. I have checked and my user has full control and verified the path.

VS is trying to access .pubmxl file that is there.

I have also tried running VS2012 as administrator.

Comment: Please check if there's any processes holding file handles on the denied file. You can do that using Sysinternals tools (Process Explorer / Process Monitor) - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals

Comment: I've seen this issue occasionally, but it's only ever once off and re-running the build makes it go away. Are you seeing it continuously?

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue ([VS2012: Access to path is denied when executing publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528835/vs2012-access-to-path-is-denied-when-executing-publish)) and found a way to allow Visual Studio access to the file.

If you open the pubxml file in Visual Studio, make an edit, and save the file, Visual Studio is able to successfully publish using that file. Hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new profile worked for me. I got this error when I tried to change the path of an existing profile, and Unfortunately I could not find the original pubxml file, otherwise I would have simply copied it to the new location and followed advice #1 (edit the file in location from VS2012). It's easy enough to create a new profile as there aren't many settings anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this issue and I noticed that the files were "Read-Only".  Selecting the files and removing the "Read-Only" attribute allowed me to Publish successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like TFS feature rocks again. Remove publish profile from local repo and get latest version afterwards, then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by removing my Publish profile and creating a new one.