# VS2012: Access to path is denied when executing publish

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When trying to publish an application (a WCF Service specifically) in VS2012, I get an error stating: "Exception in executing publishing: Access to the path [path] is denied." The file referenced is the publish profile I'm trying to execute and is type ".pubxml"

I've used SysInternals Process Explorer to check if another process has the file locked, I've closed VS2012 and reopened it with administrator rights, and have rebooted my PC.

This is the same issue described here: [VS2012 Error when creating publish package: Exception in Executing Publishing Access to path is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951164/vs2012-error-when-creating-publish-package-exception-in-executing-publishing-ac) and I'd rather comment on that question asking if he ever found a solution but unfortunately I don't have comment rights yet.

EDIT ------

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with Update 2 (11.0.60315.01 Update 2)

Comment: Don't you using VS2012RC? http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/747721/vs-2012-crashing-when-trying-to-run-publish

Comment: Also you might try `Unlocker` http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/ to find out is this file locked or is it a some other bug.

Comment: I've added my visual studio version info to the question. Regarding Unlocker, it looks like it checks the same thing SysInternals' Process Explorer checks.

Comment: have you tried making sure the destination is not marked as read only?

Comment: My user account, the SYSTEM local group, and the local Administrators group all have full control set to allow for that file and parent folder.

Comment: @Chris Unlocker not only checks, but also... well.. unlocks =)

Comment: @Drop Just downloaded and tried Unlocker. It says no locking handle found for the file I'm having problems with.

Comment: I found a workaround. By dragging the file publish profile into Visual Studio and making a change, Visual Studio gained access to it and was able to publish.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I just had the same issue crop up.

The reason why is because the files are read only.  Simply browse to the folder where the profiles are kept, select them all, and drop a click on that checkbox:

[image]

This is probably caused by your profiles being checked into source control without your knowledge.

Comment: Yeah, I've since realized that this is the reason the workaround I found works. Opening the profile in Visual Studio seems to uncheck the Read-only flag.

Comment: I checked it and it is not in read-only mode yet VS still tells me it is for some reason denied. Please help.

Comment: @Preza8 make sure you can access the destination.  Re-create your publish profile.

Comment: Deleting bin and obj folders, restarting VS and closing Git cmdline magically resolved it.

Comment: I tried this but I get a message saying I don't have permission to do it Any suggestion ?

Comment: If you don't have permission, take it.  If you can't figure out how to take ownership of a file, go ask on [su].

Comment: Thanks, It saves my lots of time :)

Answer (score 1):

on Visual Studio for **MAC**:
sudo "Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/VisualStudio" ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running your visual studio as an administrator.