# UnauthorizedAccessException error 500.35 using Piranha

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a .NET Core 2.2 app that I am building in Visual Studio Community 2019.  It works perfectly on my local machine, but gives this error when trying to publish the site to the web:

> UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   'h:\root\home\xxxxxxx-001\www\yyyyyyy\wwwroot\uploads\' is denied.

I'm new to .NET Core, and new to Piranha, and google is being less than useful.  Does anyone have any ideas? The website is tafarmerauthor.com, if you want to take a closer look.

In response to a question below:

I did give write permissions to the wwwroot and uploads folders on the server.  No change.

Comment: It looks like your app doesn't have the necessary (OS-level) permissions to interact with the 'h:\root\home\xxxxxxx-001\www\yyyyyyy\wwwroot\uploads\'  folder

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528835/vs2012-access-to-path-is-denied-when-executing-publish

Comment: @MuhammadAqib: I already saw this one, and it did not resolve the problem.